# Getting a bunch of GCC warnings

Tags: vala

A simple program to find whether there are the same letters in a string, when compiling produces a bunch of C warnings. What am I doing wrong? (The program works correctly)

```
    using Gee;
void main(string[] args) {
var s="♜♝♞♟♠♞";
unichar c;
var records = new HashMap<unichar, bool> ();

for (int i = 0; s.get_next_char (ref i, out c);) {
    stdout.printf (@"$i, $c\t");
    if (records[c]==true){
        stdout.printf("буква найдена: true\n");break;
    }else{
        records[c]=true;stdout.printf("буква не найдена: false\n");
    } 
}
}

gavr@archlabs ~/D/c/V/T / Task51> vala console.vala --pkg gee-0.8
/tmp / console.vala.BF33WZ.c: in the function " g_unichar_to_string»:
/tmp / console.vala.BF33WZ.c: 65: 27: warning: passing argument 2 " g_unichar_to_utf8 "cancels the" const " qualifier of the type [- Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  g_unichar_to_utf8 (self, _tmp1_);
                           ^~~~~~
In file included from/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib / gstring.h: 33,
                 from / usr/include/glib-2.0/glib / giochannel.h: 34,
                 from / usr/include/glib-2.0 / glib.h: 54,
                 from / tmp / console.vala.BF33WZ.c: 6.:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib / gunicode.h:844:42: note: type "gchar *" {aka "char*"} was expected, but the argument is of type "const gchar *" {aka " const char *»}
                              gchar *outbuf);
```

Comment: IMHO, `vala`  tends to be deprecated. These are just warnings given by GCC on the C code generated by `vala`. You could choose to ignore these warnings (or else patch the `vala` transpiler to improve the C code generation by adding explicit casts)

Comment: I do not think so, the last update was February 2. https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala

Comment: Vala is deprecated in the same way that C is - people who don't like it don't use it.

Comment: Then consider reporting a bug to Vala, and if possible propose a patch fixing that precise issue.

Comment: It already has been: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/issues/725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468977/6339452), you're not doing anything wrong, it's just the C compiler doesn't have as much information as the vala compiler does, and hence complains about some of the C code that valac generates.