# How to overcome warning about functioni argument being const in vala?

Tags: vala

Vala code warning about a function expecting a non-const argument but being given const.

Vala code:

```
Gtk.TreeSelection treeSelection = treeview.get_selection();      
Gtk.TreeModel treeModel = treeview.get_model();                  
List<Gtk.TreePath> treePaths = treeSelection.get_selected_rows(out treeModel);
Gtk.TreeIter treeIter;                                           
List<Gtk.TreeRowReference> treeRowRefs = new List<Gtk.TreeRowReference>();

foreach (unowned Gtk.TreePath treePath in treePaths) {           
   treeRowRefs.append(new Gtk.TreeRowReference(treeModel, treePath));
}                                                                
foreach (unowned Gtk.TreeRowReference treeRowRef in treeRowRefs) {
   if (treeModel.get_iter(out treeIter, treeRowRef.get_path())) {
       fileListStore.remove(treeIter);                  
   }                                                        
}
```

vala compiler warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_tree_row_reference_get_path’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
 _tmp17_ = gtk_tree_row_reference_get_path (_tmp16_);


In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkcombobox.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkappchooserbutton.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:42,
                 from /home/user/syswrite/syswrite.vala.c:9:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtktreemodel.h:267:22: note: expected ‘struct GtkTreeRowReference *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct GtkTreeRowReference *’
GtkTreePath         *gtk_tree_row_reference_get_path  (GtkTreeRowReference *reference);
```

How to overcome this warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding vala compilation warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468179/understanding-vala-compilation-warnings)

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468977/6339452), you're not doing anything wrong, it's just the C compiler doesn't have as much information as the vala compiler does, and hence complains about some of the C code that valac generates.